# Django static files troubleshooting for production

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

INSTALLED_APPS has 'django.contrib.staticfiles'

This is how they're called in HTML
<img src="{% static 'capabilities-2.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid">

Displayed in my console:
[10/Sep/2022 17:39:50] "GET /css/index_styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[10/Sep/2022 17:39:50] "GET /js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[10/Sep/2022 17:39:51] "GET /static/index/images/capabilities-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[10/Sep/2022 17:39:51] "GET /assets/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

Trying to transition from Dev to Production. I had the images working in development.

If I inspect the images (or lack of images) within a browser, the path is as follows:

Should be noted that I can't even see them when inspecting the source.

I tried adjusting the paths /static/capabilities-2.jpg to /static/index/images/capabilities-2.jpg as it is in my project but that still didn't work.

I'm running on Linode, Ubuntu 22.04. I like a lot about Django, but static files are being a huge PIMA.

Answer (score 0):

The Django static file server is for use only during development. During production, use your webserver's static files capability:

- [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/getting-started.html#content)
- [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)

Or if you're using a different one, look at the documentation and/or Google it.